# Jquery Google Maps stylers attribute

Tags: jquery, google-maps

What is wrong in my statement, my stylers attribute is not working :-(

```
$(function() {

      $("#P9_MAP").goMap({
        streetViewControl: true,
        navigationControl: true,
        maptype: 'ROADMAP',
        mapTypeControl: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
          position: 'TOP_RIGHT',
          style: 'DEFAULT'
        },
        address: '',
        stylers: {saturation:-100},
        markers: [
          {......
```

Comment: Are you using the standard [Google Maps Javascript API (v3)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference)?

Answer (score 0):

It's not supposed to be

> stylers: {saturation:-100},

Try instead:

```
styles: {stylers:[{saturation:-100}]},
```

For greater info on styling maps, plus also see the link at bottom of this page to googles Styled Map Wizard, read:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling